# usage of Me v. myself

Tags: grammar

Is "Feel free to reach out to **myself**, Howard, or Jane." correct?
Or, should it read "Feel free to reach out to **me**, Howard, or Jane.".

Comment: "me" would be normal usage - at least in British English.

Comment: Older speakers of Southern US English did this all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @James Random and @TrevorD: **me** is preferred in this case.

> Reach out [verb phrase] to [preposition] *person or group of people* [indirect object].

When the first person [I] assumes the role of an indirect object, the standard morphology is **[me](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/me)**.

If the speaker and the object are the same, the utterance is expressed **[reflexively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb)**. This means I/myself; you/yourself. Since in your example, the person doing the "reaching" and the person(s) being "reached" are not the same, using *myself* would not be conventional

In speech, as has been pointed out, grammar is more fluid and several different aspects of the same concept can stand in for one another because a speaker, unlike a writer, can always keep uttering more words until their message is clear.